# UISegmented Control ObjectAtIndex replacement for swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

After Switching to swift i cannot find the object at index for a segmented control

this is how i've been doing it

```
[[segmentedControl subviews] objectAtIndex:0]
```

What is the equivalent for the above line in swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UISegmentedControl` is a descendant from `UIView` which holds the `subviews` array, so

```
segmentedControl.subViews[0]
```